# Anyone having problem deploying a lambda function with serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am getting this error when trying to deploy a simple function.

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  ServerlessError: Inaccessible host: `cloudformation.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `us-west-2' region.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           10.15.3
     Serverless Version:     1.38.0
```

Comment: Do a `dig +short cloudformation.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` and see what you get.

Comment: can you share your serverless template for better understanding and check your all services mentioned in template are available in us-west-2 region?